# Is there any option to change the contrast on Blender Render?

Tags: rendering, materials

If **I'm using Blender Render**, and i want to render an Animation, before anything on the settings, can i set the contrast?

Answer (score 2):

There is no option for contrast but you can change it in the node editor under
Add node -> color -> brightness/contrasts connect the scene node to the brightness/contrasts node and then to the render output node NOTE you need to click
The use nodes button first